# Is there a way to debug Apollo GraphQL subscriptions in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: graphql, google-chrome-devtools, apollo-client, graphql-subscriptions

In the `Network` tab of the Chrome DevTools, I can only find GraphQL queries and mutations requests:

[image]

While listening to a GraphQL subscription, and receiving a response, nothing appears in this tab. Is there another place to fetch GraphQL subscription from the Chrome DevTools?

For information, I am using `apollo-client` with `apollo-angular`.

Comment: subscriptions usually are over web sockets

Comment: I hadn't noticed the `WS` tab under the `Network` tab. If you like, you can post it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `Network` tab of the Chrome DevTools, you should switch the filter to `WS` to see and debug your Apollo GraphQL subscription. You can see it in the pictures below:
[image]