# Apollo useSubscription doesn't work for new windows

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphql-subscriptions

This is my first time using useSub and I noticed that although my backend sends it's responses to the client (at least the console.log shows it is). The client using useSub doesn't do anything. I usually use subscribeToMore with query, but for this job I want to only get the most updated info. Is there a way to check if useSub connects correctly? Or is it broken in "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.3"

Query

```
export const INCOMING_VIDEO_CHAT = gql`
  subscription {
    incomingVideoChat {
      rn
      p
    }
  }
`;
```

Client

```
const { data, loading } = useSubscription(INCOMING\_VIDEO\_CHAT, {
onSubscriptionData: ({ subscriptionData }) => {
console.log(subscriptionData);
}
});
```

Server:

```
module.exports = {
type: chatInfoType,
subscribe: () => pubsub.asyncIterator(INCOMING\_VIDEO\_CHAT),
async resolve(payload, { }, req) {
if (auth.isAuthenticated(req)) {
if (!payload) {
return;
}
const { userID, rn, p } = payload;
  try {
    if (req.id === userID) {
      return { rn, p };
    } else {
      return;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e);
  }
}
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Chrome Dev Tools to check if `useSubscription` connects correctly. In the Network tab of the Chrome DevTools, you should switch the filter to WS to see and debug your Apollo GraphQL subscription. You should read [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62054807/is-there-a-way-to-debug-apollo-graphql-subscriptions-in-chrome-devtools/62077106#62077106).